# I can do addition, substraction and division but i cannot do multiplication

Tags: vhdl, data-operator

Here are my topmodule and testbench files. What is my mistake?

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity celcius_to_fah is  
  Port ( c : in unsigned (6 downto 0);
         f : out unsigned (8 downto 0));
  constant coef: unsigned(7 downto 0):="00100000";
end celcius_to_fah;

architecture dataflow_model of celcius_to_fah is
begin
  f <= coef2*c;
end dataflow_model;
```

testbench

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity sim is
end sim;

architecture dataflow of sim is
  component celcius_to_fah
     Port ( c : in unsigned (6 downto 0);
            f : out unsigned (8 downto 0));
  end component;

  signal ct: unsigned (6 downto 0):="0000100";
  signal ft: unsigned (8 downto 0);

begin

  uut: celcius_to_fah port map(c=>ct , f=>ft);

  process
  begin
    wait for 5ns;
    ct<="0001000";
  end process;

end dataflow;
```

Comment: What answer do you expect for ft, and what value do you actually see for ft? Have you tried doing the math on scratch paper so see what the result should be? Have you tried other values of ct to see if any of them might produce a correct value for ft?

Comment: finally i solved my question...  i learned that i must define an 15 bit unsigned vector output for multiplication because i have 7 bit and 8 bit inputs. 7+8=15 bit. This is a true statement but i cannot prove that. Can anybody explain why i must define 15bit output vector ?

Comment: What is coef2? Do you have enough bits for the product?

Comment: Neither one of your design files are valid VHDL, both missing q use clauses(`use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;`) providing visibility for the declaration for type std_ulogic when converting string literals to unsigned arrays. What tool? `coef2` is not declared. "*"[unsigned, unsigned return unsigned] provides a result that has a length the sum of it's two operand's lengths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that you have identified the solution, I'll help you understand why.

You are multiplying a 7-bit number with a maximum value of 127 by an 8-bit number with a maximum value of 255. If you do the math you find that the maximum value of the product is 32,385 which needs at least 15 bits to be represented as a binary number.

The actual value that you used for coef2 was 32, so for small values of c you got the correct value for f. If you know that the coefficient will actually fit in 6 bits then you would only need 13 bits for the product.

Comment: Let's not forget to mention that multiplying numbers in base \$b\$ with exponent \$m\$ and \$n\$ is the same as adding the exponents. Like this: \$b^m×b^n=b^{m+n}\$. In OP's case it's simply \$2^7×2^8=2^{7+8}=2^{15}\$. [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Positive_exponents)